# Unzipping a zip file through ADF is giving a special character

Tags: azure-data-factory, unzip

We are extracting a zip file in SFTP and we are trying to unzip it through ADF. While unzipping it is giving a special character in the file as below

Actual data
|"QLD Mackay"|

After unzipping through ADF
|"QLD |"56ay"|

But when we manually try to unzip, we are not getting this issue.

Can someone help with this issue, please?

Comment: Show your code. We have no clue what you're dong unless you show the code that does the unzipping for you. Also, why do you have the pipe symbol surrounding the `actual data`?

Comment: we are using a copy activity to unzip the file in ADF with compression type as None. The file is pipe-delimited that is why the pipe is present around the data

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought this was the name of your file. Are you sure the actual data is from the same row? I've seen ADF throw fits at times when encountering some special characters. If this is the exact data that ends up mangled, I'd suggest asking Microsoft Support. Seeing you're not using any code, I'm not sure that there's much anyone here can do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data does not have any unknown characters in it. I have repro'd with sample data and was able to unzip the file without any issues.

**Example:**

I am using a binary dataset for source and sink to unzip the zip file using azure data factory copy data activity.

1. In the source dataset, select compression type as ZipDeflate.

[image]

[image]

2. Connect sink to sink dataset with compression type none. In sink settings, select copy behavior as Preserve hierarchy to preserve the source filename.

[image]